# Frame drops while playing video on second monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics, fps

So, this is driving me nuts. I've got a dual screen setup where I run my other 1440x900 monitor off my processor's integrated graphics. Every time I'm watching a stream or watching youtube or a movie on the second monitor, the game that's running on my primary monitor suffers a drop of 15 to 20 FPS. That is a very significant drop on a system that shouldn't be experiencing any kind of trouble with that setup by any means. Does anyone know what's causing it and how to fix it? I've got proper up to date drivers for both my GPU and Intel HD. Both processor and GPU utilization percentages and temperatures are within normal parameters.

My specs are:

- MSI Z170A Pro
- Intel i5 6600k
- GeForce 1070
- 16GB RAM

I really appreciate any help that you guys can give. Nobody deserves frame drops like these :(

Comment: Why are both monitors not connected to the dedicated GPU?

Comment: @Ramhound The monitor has VGA input only. The 1070 doesn't have a VGA output sadly :(
Besides, wouldn't it only be a positive influence on my FPS if it didn't run off the graphics card? Not trying to sound sarcastic, just genuinely curious if I'm understanding it wrong.

Comment: No; It wouldn't effect your FPS at least not in my experience

Comment: Do you have a VGA -> DVI adapter? Most graphics cards will come with one. You'd be much, much better off plugging them into your dedicated GPU.

Comment: Watching a video while your playing a game will effect your FPS you can't get around that unless you configure your browser to use the iGPU even then your CPU will effect the FPS so that's a wash

Comment: @JaredT It's a DVI-D port, meaning it outputs a digital signal. Those small adapters you're thinking of can't convert digital to analog.